# Create png from UIImageViews iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm developing an iOs app for iPad. I'm displaying a grid with imageviews and I would like to make a png image from all the images, but with diferent pixel size. I mean, I can't do a screenshot, I have to create an image of the image views but with another resolution. Bigger.

Comment: You can merge UIImage's using UIGraphicsBeginImageContext & UIGraphicsEndImageContext. Check on how to merge two images and try to extend this to multiple images.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample from a previous SO post that presents a similar issue. ([SO Post Joining X Images Together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021711/how-do-i-join-x-number-of-uiimages-together))

Accepted result code:

```
+ (UIImage *)joinImages:(UIImage *)im1 secondImage:(UIImage *)im2 thirdImage:(UIImage *)im3
{
//Joins 3 UIImages together, stitching them vertically
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(320, 480);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

CGPoint image1Point = CGPointMake(0, 0);
[im1 drawAtPoint:image1Point];

CGPoint image2Point = CGPointMake(0, im1.size.height);
[im2 drawAtPoint:image2Point];

CGPoint image3Point = CGPointMake(0, im1.size.height +im2.size.height);
[im3 drawAtPoint:image3Point];

UIImage* finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return finalImage;
}
```

You could use that as a sample, based on your needs it sounds like you may want to take the image sizes and scale them to fit.

Comment: I'll try it and I tell you something!

Comment: Just rereading your problem i'm thinking for example with a 9 image grid, 3x3, you'd want to keep track of the rows and positions so it would be something like the code posted, then that would give you a 3x1 column then repeat that process and move the x position over the width of one image, that should give you three rows and two columns, then lastly move x 2image widths and then you'd get 3x3