# -[UIImage drawInRect:] / CGContextDrawImage() not releasing memory?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, uiimage

I wanted to easily blend a UIImage on top of another background image, so wrote a category method for UIImage, adapted from [blend two uiimages based on alpha/transparency of top image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309757/blend-two-uiimages) :

```
- (UIImage *) blendedImageOn:(UIImage *) backgroundImage  {
 NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(backgroundImage.size);

 CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, backgroundImage.size.width, backgroundImage.size.height);
 [backgroundImage drawInRect:rect];
 [self drawInRect:rect];
 UIImage* blendedImage = [UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() retain];

 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
 [pool release];

 return [blendedImage autorelease];
}
```

Unfortunately my app that uses the above method to load around 20 images and blend them with background and gloss images (so probably around 40 calls), is being jettisoned on the device.

An Instruments session revealed that calls to malloc stemming from the calls to drawInRect: are responsible for the bulk of the memory usage. I tried replacing the drawInRect: messages with equivalent function calls to the function CGContextDrawImage but it didn't help. The AutoReleasePool was added after I found the memory usage problem; it also didn't make a difference.

I'm thinking this is probably because I'm not using graphics contexts appropriately. Would calling the above method in a loop be a bad idea because of the number of contexts I create? Or did I simply miss something?

-
Edit 1: thanks for the comments. The method is invoked in a controller method that sets up 20 views, so in a loop I have the following call:

```
    UIImage *blendedImage = [newImage blendedImageOn:backgroundImage];
```

I added the autorelease pool to make sure the images are released before the main autorelease pool will release them, so theoretically all of the new UIImages objects should be released when the loop has finished. The profiling results don't show any difference whether the autorelease pool is in there or not.

-
Edit 2: And yes, I've tried adding an autorelease pool before the call to blendedImageOn: as well, to no effect.

-
Edit 3: fixed embarrassing bug of UIImage being released because of the autorelease pool. The intention of the autorelease pool is to release any objects *other than* the result UIImage, in case the excessive memory is due to temporary objects added to the main autorelease pool which are not freed immediately.

The question I was trying to ask (very badly, I admit!) is: why does calling this method 20 times result in a lot of memory usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem for the excessive memory usage. My images were much bigger than I'd anticipated, and resizing the background image to the view size before invoking the posted method that draws them into the graphics context, solved the memory usage.

I'm still puzzled why the memory isn't reclaimed when the image context is ended.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call `drawRect:` method directly. use `[self setNeddsDisplay];` instead (it won't help you with this leak);

About your leak. remove everything about pool. 
Your method returns autoreleased `UIImage` object.
Please paste code where you're using returned `UIImage` and I'll be able to help you. 
Very likely that you should make pool in place where you invoke `blendedImageOn:` and drain the pool each 3-5 iterations.

Comment: It's drawInRect, to write one image to another. Pretty sure setNeedsDisplay will not do that!

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, read drawRect: instead of drawInRect.
Anyway 2nd part of the answer remains. It is better to show how author invokes blendedImageOn method.

Comment: True. +1 for catching the autoreleased object in the pool. (That sounds all wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

One problem with your code is that the blendedImage object you get is marked for autorelease and when you release the temporary autorelease pool, poof, you release blendedImage too.

You could retain until until the pool is released, then return it autoreleased:

```
...
UIImage* blendedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[blendedImage retain];       // keep this past pool release
[pool release];

[blendedimage autorelease];  // now it will be autoreleased from the main pool

return [blendedImage release];  // release to balance out the retain above
```

Comment: progrmr, good catch. I have in fact posted in-troubleshooting code that doesn't exhibit my symptoms but is demonstrating an entirely different memory problem as you pointed out. All, sorry for the mess :-(

I've edited the code and re-phrased the problem description in the hopes it will clarify the problem I'm having.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [iPhone memory usage guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-BEHDEDDB), any method that returns an "owned" object (not autoreleased) should start with "alloc" or "new", or it should contain "copy".

Your name "blendedImageOn" doesn't follow these guidelines. If you use it in a month, or someone else uses it, you won't remember that the image is retained inside and you'll have a memory leak.

Comment: Good point on the name, I guess the name should be the more verbose 'imageByBlendingImage:'.

The method isn't returning an 'owned' object however, as the retain count should be balanced to 0 when returning, due to the autorelease. This complies with the memory usage guidelines: 

_You relinquish ownership of an object by sending it a release message or an autorelease message (autorelease is discussed in more detail in “Autorelease”). In Cocoa terminology, relinquishing ownership of an object is therefore typically referred to as “releasing” an object._

Comment: Sorry about that.. It seems that I was either commenting an old version of the code, or I didn't see clearly ;-) Of course it looks now the code returns an autoreleased object and the method name is alright.