# iphone 4 - How do I record the video overlay on top of the video also?

Tags: iphone, video, overlay, record

Does anyone know how to do this?

Is anyone able to provide an example? I believe this is out of NDA now as was available in version 4.0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand, what you are trying to do corectly, you have set up video capture someting like suggested by Apple in this Q&A:http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2010/qa1702.html

From there it shouldn't be much of a Problem to use the method described in this answer:[blend two uiimages based on alpha/transparency of top image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309757/blend-two-uiimages) to blend the preview with your overlay, provided you draw it in a UIImage first. Feed the resulting images to a buffer and save it accordingly.

Though, this method most certainly wouldn't give you a lot of frames per second.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to AVFoundation framework , specially to avcapture avsession avinputdevice, etc. You can find some listings in the iPhone dev center forums: search "avcapture"
AVFoundation is the framework you want to use to record, modify raw frames, show them, an offcourse add some overlay

If you want to do only overlay then, UIImagePickerController should b enough.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I'm able to capture video with the picker so hopefully some further research into this framework will help. Links to resources appreciated if anyone has any!

Comment: If someone is able to help out with a working example, sample code or resource that works, bounty is all yours!