# Blending UIImage with alpha value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage

How to blend two images by changing alfa of only one image so that the upper image will be slightly transparent and the above image will be displayed as it is drawn on the background image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309757/blend-two-uiimages

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through  imageView alpha property

```
imageView.alpha = 0.0f;
```

**Detailed code:**

```
   UIImage *bottomImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomImage.png"];
    UIImage *topImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topImage.png"];

    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );

    // Use existing opacity as is
    [bottomImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    // Apply supplied opacity
    [topImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.8];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

see more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309757/blend-two-uiimages)

Comment: I have the above code but when i change the alpha value background image alpha also changes.