# How do I combine two ore more CIImage

Tags: ios, swift, ciimage

How do I combine two or more CIImage into another one. I tried using ciContext.drawImage. How do I get a CGImage from it ?? What I have understood is that I am writing into a context from which I should be able to get an Image. Please let me know if I have understood anything wrong.

```
let eaglContext = EAGLContext(API: .OpenGLES2)
let ciContext = CIContext(EAGLContext: eaglContext)
ciContext.drawImage(firstCIImage, inRect: firstRect, fromRect: secondRect)
ciContext.drawImage(secondCIImage, inRect: secondRect, fromRect: secondRect)
```

Answer (score 4):

You may try something like that:

```
    var outputImage: CIImage?
    let images : Array<CIImage> = [] // add all your CIImages that you'd like to combine
    for image in images {
        outputImage = outputImage == nil ? image : image.imageByCompositingOverImage(outputImage!)
    }
    var cgImage: CGImageRef
    if let image = outputImage {
        let eaglContext = EAGLContext(API: .OpenGLES2)
        let ciContext = CIContext(EAGLContext: eaglContext)
        cgImage = ciContext.createCGImage(image, fromRect: image.extent)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use CIFilter-s for that :)

[tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22167/beginning-core-image-in-ios-6)

Comment: I agree with sloik. Core Image Filters are the right tool for this task.

Comment: Sorry, I am still not able to do it. CIFilters need a image to be initialized. Which image should i initialise it with and what should be the filtername ? I have firstCIImage and secondCIImage and i want to combine it to form thirdCIImage. A code example will be very helpful

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472415/xcode-compositing-with-alpha-using-core-image