# Saving an image on top of another image in Swift

Tags: iphone, image, swift

I am learning Swift and I am creating an app that uses a personal photo and puts another on top of it. I now have a hacky solution, to create a screenshot of the area and save it. I need to do this in Swift

```
@IBAction func saveImage(sender: AnyObject) {
    //Create the UIImage
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.frame.size)
    view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    //Save it to the camera roll
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

But, this was working and isn't anymore. But, this is also not the best solution.

So guys, how can I save an image to the camera roll from a personal image, with an image as overlay?

Help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [blend two uiimages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309757/blend-two-uiimages)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I would recommend reading through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309757/blend-two-uiimages) thread. All your answers are there. Once you read through that article, the following code sample should help you composite the two images together properly.

```
func saveImage() {
    let bottomImage = UIImage(named: "bottom")!
    let topImage = UIImage(named: "top")!

    let newSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100) // set this to what you need
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)

    bottomImage.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: newSize))
    topImage.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: newSize))

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
```

Hopefully this gets you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 11):

Apple advises against UIGraphicsBeginImageContext, so as long as your app does not support devices older than iOS 10, then use something like this:

```
private func drawLogoIn(_ image: UIImage, _ logo: UIImage, position: CGPoint) -> UIImage {
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: image.size)
    return renderer.image { context in
        image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: image.size))
        logo.draw(in: CGRect(origin: position, size: logo.size))
    }
}
```

Besides performance gains, you get full P3 range.

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE FOR SWIFT 4**

```
func saveImage() {
    let bottomImage = UIImage(named: "your bottom image name")!
    let topImage = UIImage(named: "your top image name")!            
    let newSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)   // set this to what you need
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)
    bottomImage.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: newSize))
    topImage.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: newSize))
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
```

To use the image just refer to `newImage`

**EXAMPLE HOW TO USE THE IMAGE:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageButton: UIButton!
imageButton.setBackgroundImage(newImage), for: .normal)
```

This is an edit of [cnoon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29063617/7311767) but optimized for Swift 4.

Answer (score 3):

Updated to Swift 3.0:

```
func saveImage() {
    let bottomImage = UIImage(named: "bottom")!
    let topImage = UIImage(named: "top")!

    let newSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100) // set this to what you need
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)

    bottomImage.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: newSize))//As drawInRect is deprecated
    topImage.draw(at: CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: newSize))//As drawInRect is deprecated

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
```

Comment: it looses its resolution