# Objective C compare 2 images and get the differences highlighted

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv

I am building an application, where I need to compare 2 images and highlight the difference. For example I am comparing UIImage1 with UIImage2, where both the images are same, except there is an extra small square object in UIImage2. I need to highlight the extra square object with red color in the UIImage2.

I am not sure, how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You can subtract two UIImages by blending them with the blendmode "kCGBlendModeDifference".

Here is an example done, you just have to change the blendmode:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3188761

Comment: This highlights the extra elements, that is great. But can we change the highlight color?